# Why is the Queen Anne flintlock pistol named after Queen Anne?

Tags: 1600s

Why is the [Queen Anne flintlock pistol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Anne_pistol) named after Queen Anne? She didn't reign until the early 1700's, and the pistol was created about 50 years before?

Comment: What is a queen anne flintlock? Do you have an image? Any reference?? What has your preliminary research shown?  What was wrong with the answers in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Anne_pistol)?

Comment: Specfically, Wikipedia says "they came in fashion in England during the reign of Anne, Queen of Great Britain, hence the name." Why is this not enough?

Answer (score 1):

A basic historical truth: the names things are known by centuries later are often not their original names. The modern concept of brand names did not exist during the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries.

The name that the original inventor gave to this kind of pistol is probably lost; many other gunsmiths would have made similar weapons under their own nomenclature. Since this kind of pistol became popular during the reign of Queen Anne, the name was likely applied *after* Anne's time to refer to the pistols common then.